# Implementar metodo en fragment

Tags: android, método, fragment

hace mucho deje de programar y bueno, ahora que estoy en desarrollo estoy en un lio. Lo que sucede es que tengo una aplicacion con navigation drawer y que llama fragments. Ahora, segui un tutorial de hacer login con firebase y quiero que la opcion de logout este en un fragmento, el fragmento de settings, pero no consigo hacer que funcione. Tengo un metodo logout en mainActivity y no puedo llamarlo desde el fragmento, como podria hacer que funcione.
Adjunto metodo:

```
public void logOut(View view){
    firebaseAuth.signOut();

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if(status.isSuccess()){
                goLogInScreen();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No se pudo cerrar sesión",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

y el fragmento:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    btnLogout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
            main.logOut(v);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: espero mi respuesta te ayude :)

Comment: respuesta actualizada, nos avisas como te va

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo ideal es que lo hagas con interfaces, pero por ahora puedes hacerlo así:

```
 btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).logOut(v);
        }
    });
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias!, de momento me ha funcionado, si no es mucha molestia, como podria hacerlo con interfaces o donde puedo buscar mas para poder implementarlo, teniendo en cuenta que no manejo mucho java.

Comment: Ok, primero puedes marcar mi respuesta como aceptada, y voto arriba :D  , te dejo este link para que repases: https://desarrollador-android.com/desarrollo/formacion/empezar-formacion/crear-una-interfaz-de-usuario-dinamica-con-fragments/comunicarse-con-otros-fragments/